# SSIS: Error --> Could not create a managed connection manager (VS 2010 - AdoNet MySql)

Tags: .net, ssis

I just upgraded my Connector/C# for Visual Studio and I get the error above.
Everything seems fine, the preview queries work just fine in the package but upon execution this error occurs.

- Before upgrading everything worked fine
- I have deleted the pervious connection manager and added a totally new one
- Test connection is succesfull

Anyone with the same problem in the past?
There is a lot of speculation on 32/64 bit OSes, though MySQL official website states that even though the installer says x86, that means nothing 
(Note: MySQL Installer is 32 bit, but will install both 32 bit and 64 bit binaries.).

EDIT -> I tried connecting manually through an SSIS script to see if the coded exception provided more info. Unfortunatelly it provided even less

```
ConnectionManager connMan = Dts.Connections[7];
try
{
    connMan.AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Dts.Events.FireError(-1, "Elt-Proc:", ex.Message, "", 0);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the answer:

Problem was with VS-2010, SSIS, and latest ADO .Net connector / MySQL For Visual studio.

I had installed the latest Connector/Net 6.7.4 and the MySQL for Visual Studio.
I noticed that the version in the string at the connection properties was 6.6.5.

So I uninstalled the 6.7.4 version and re-installed the 6.6.5 version and worked like a charm.

I hope this will help others as well. It took way too much time for me to find out.

**IMPORTANT:**
This error will also occur (on the server side) if SSIS Server and VISUAL STUDIO DEV Computer have different Connector/.Net Versions

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the right path Athanasios, I was stuck with an unhelpful error message in SSDT.  I've since found there is a MySql bug for this that explains the issue and why:   http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69768.

Comment: This is an old question, but in case someone finds it helpful: The version number (major.minor.patch) inside the conmgr file in the CreationName eg Version=6.8.3.0 has to match the version of the MySQL Connector Net that can be seen in the Control Panel in Add/Remove Programs