# SSIS Error: Could not create a managed connection manager when using VS 2022 and Oracle 19c ADO.NET Connection Manager

Tags: ssis, ado.net, visual-studio-2022, oracle19c

I'm in need of some assistance with configuring VS SSIS 2022 & Oracle 19c ADO.net Connection Manager/Extensions/Developer Tools.

I have clearly established connections to two of our Oracle 19c databases. However when I execute my data flow routine I get the following message:

[image: SSIS Screenshot]

[UBFIRST FindMissingBal SQL [2]] Error: ADO NET Source has failed to acquire the connection {C681E778-A190-4C7F-A35E-2E4C4187F075} with the following error message: "Could not create a managed connection manager.".

I found similar issues explaining the likely cause is non-matching drivers, or incompatible.
[SSIS: Error --> Could not create a managed connection manager (VS 2010 - AdoNet MySql)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120800/ssis-error-could-not-create-a-managed-connection-manager-vs-2010-adonet?newreg=d75ae41758764ada81e29f5913c6d3ee)

I have walked through this Oracle/Microsoft Tools documentation and installed the Data Tools.
https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/ocmt.html

Here's as much documentation to offer as I can think of from other people's suggestions:

-Connection Manager Properties
Qualifier: Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.21.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342

-VS 2022 Manage Extensions:
[image: VS2022 Manage Extensions]

-Help: About VS 2022
[image: VS Installed Products]

And lastly, I clearly am connecting to the database and returning data via "Preview Query Results".

Thank you for any help anyone has to offer, I've been chasing this for the better part of 3-days now.....
[image: database results]

I've researched the issue for 3-days and am very close because I'm clearly returning results from one database, but cannot get the ADO.NET Destination task to complete.

I'm confused on which driver/tools version #'s to verify to realize which part needs updating.

Comment: When it fails, does it fail in Visual Studio or have you deployed it to a server?

Comment: It fails in VS, eventually I'll deploy it to a server where we use Task Scheduler to kick SSIS off.

Comment: Might try going to the Project settings and change the execution model from 64 bit to 32 bit mode.